# javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Cannot create an abstract class

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

Hi any help will be a good assistant for this issue I have
    Any idea why I get this error when my client call a webservice ?
it is a cxf client running on JBoss . when I call the convert method on my client  IPdfUtilitiesService_BasicHttpBindingIPdfUtilitiesService_Client I'm getting SOAPFaultException :

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Cannot create an abstract class.
            at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:157)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy136.convert(Unknown Source)
            at leumi.pdfutilities.service.IPdfUtilitiesService_BasicHttpBindingIPdfUtilitiesService_Client.convert(IPdfUtilitiesService_BasicHttpBindingIPdfUtilitiesService_Client.java:72)
            at ext.mesarim.out.Html2PdfConverter.getPdf(Html2PdfConverter.java:73)
            at ext.mesarim.out.Html2PdfConverter.getPdf(Html2PdfConverter.java:127)
            at ext.mesarim.out.MesarimHtmlParser.parse(MesarimHtmlParser.java:142)
            at calypsox.tk.bo.document.GatewayMesarimDocumentSender.send(GatewayMesarimDocumentSender.java:136)
            at com.calypso.engine.advice.SenderEngine.handleEvent(SenderEngine.java:358)
            at com.calypso.engine.advice.SenderEngine.process(SenderEngine.java:217)
            at com.calypso.engine.Engine$EngineThread.run(Engine.java:1413)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Cannot create an abstract class.
            at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.unmarshalFault(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:84)
            at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:51)
            at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:40)
            at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
            at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:113)
            at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:69)
            at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:34)
            at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
            at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:845)
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1624)
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1513)
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1318)
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:632)
            at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
            at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
            at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:570)
            at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:479)
            at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)
            at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)
            at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
            at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135)
                ... 9 more

My wsdl :


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<wsdl:definitions name="PdfUtilitiesService"
      targetNamespace="http://Leumi/PdfUtilities/Service/2015/04" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
      xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
      xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
      xmlns:tns="http://Leumi/PdfUtilities/Service/2015/04" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
      xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy"
      xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract"
      xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
      xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata">

      <!--  <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BasicHttpBinding_IPdfUtilitiesService_policy">

            <wsp:ExactlyOne>

                  <wsp:All>
                        <http:NegotiateAuthentication
                              xmlns:http="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/06/2004/policy/http" />
                  </wsp:All>
            </wsp:ExactlyOne>
      </wsp:Policy>-->

      <wsdl:types>

            <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://Leumi/PdfUtilities/Service/2015/04/Imports">
                  <xsd:import
                        schemaLocation="http://ntas107704t67/WsPdfUtilities/PdfUtilitiesService.svc?xsd=xsd0"
                        namespace="http://Leumi/PdfUtilities/Service/2015/04" />
                  <xsd:import
                        schemaLocation="http://ntas107704t67/WsPdfUtilities/PdfUtilitiesService.svc?xsd=xsd1"
                        namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
                  <xsd:import
                        schemaLocation="http://ntas107704t67/WsPdfUtilities/PdfUtilitiesService.svc?xsd=xsd2"
                        namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Drawing" />
            </xsd:schema>
      </wsdl:types>

      <wsdl:message name="IPdfUtilitiesService_Convert_InputMessage">
            <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Convert" />
      </wsdl:message>

      <wsdl:message name="IPdfUtilitiesService_Convert_OutputMessage">
            <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ConvertResponse" />
      </wsdl:message>

      <wsdl:message name="IPdfUtilitiesService_Modify_InputMessage">
            <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Modify" />
      </wsdl:message>

      <wsdl:message name="IPdfUtilitiesService_Modify_OutputMessage">
            <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ModifyResponse" />
      </wsdl:message>

      <wsdl:message name="IPdfUtilitiesService_Merge_InputMessage">
            <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Merge" />
      </wsdl:message>

      <wsdl:message name="IPdfUtilitiesService_Merge_OutputMessage">
            <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:MergeResponse" />
      </wsdl:message>

      <wsdl:message name="IPdfUtilitiesService_GetFileInfo_InputMessage">
            <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetFileInfo" />
      </wsdl:message>

      <wsdl:message name="IPdfUtilitiesService_GetFileInfo_OutputMessage">
            <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetFileInfoResponse" />
      </wsdl:message>

      <wsdl:portType name="IPdfUtilitiesService">

            <wsdl:operation name="Convert">
                  <wsdl:input
                        wsaw:Action="http://Leumi/PdfUtilities/Service/2015/04/IPdfUtilitiesService/Convert"
                        message="tns:IPdfUtilitiesService_Convert_InputMessage" />
                  <wsdl:output
                        wsaw:Action="http://Leumi/PdfUtilities/Service/2015/04/IPdfUtilitiesService/ConvertResponse"
                        message="tns:IPdfUtilitiesService_Convert_OutputMessage" />
            </wsdl:operation>

            <wsdl:operation name="Modify">
                  <wsdl:input
                        wsaw:Action="http://Leumi/PdfUtilities/Service/2015/04/IPdfUtilitiesService/Modify"
                        message="tns:IPdfUtilitiesService_Modify_InputMessage" />
                  <wsdl:output
                        wsaw:Action="http://Leumi/PdfUtilities/Service/2015/04/IPdfUtilitiesService/ModifyResponse"
                        message="tns:IPdfUtilitiesService_Modify_OutputMessage" />
            </wsdl:operation>

            <wsdl:operation name="Merge">
                  <wsdl:input
                        wsaw:Action="http://Leumi/PdfUtilities/Service/2015/04/IPdfUtilitiesService/Merge"
                        message="tns:IPdfUtilitiesService_Merge_InputMessage" />
                  <wsdl:output
                        wsaw:Action="http://Leumi/PdfUtilities/Service/2015/04/IPdfUtilitiesService/MergeResponse"
                        message="tns:IPdfUtilitiesService_Merge_OutputMessage" />
            </wsdl:operation>

            <wsdl:operation name="GetFileInfo">
                  <wsdl:input
                        wsaw:Action="http://Leumi/PdfUtilities/Service/2015/04/IPdfUtilitiesService/GetFileInfo"
                        message="tns:IPdfUtilitiesService_GetFileInfo_InputMessage" />
                  <wsdl:output
                        wsaw:Action="http://Leumi/PdfUtilities/Service/2015/04/IPdfUtilitiesService/GetFileInfoResponse"
                        message="tns:IPdfUtilitiesService_GetFileInfo_OutputMessage" />
            </wsdl:operation>
      </wsdl:portType>

      <wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPdfUtilitiesService"
            type="tns:IPdfUtilitiesService">
            <!-- <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#BasicHttpBinding_IPdfUtilitiesService_policy" /> -->
            <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />

            <wsdl:operation name="Convert">
                  <soap:operation
                        soapAction="http://Leumi/PdfUtilities/Service/2015/04/IPdfUtilitiesService/Convert"
                        style="document" />

                  <wsdl:input>
                        <soap:body use="literal" />
                  </wsdl:input>

                  <wsdl:output>
                        <soap:body use="literal" />
                  </wsdl:output>
            </wsdl:operation>

            <wsdl:operation name="Modify">
                  <soap:operation
                        soapAction="http://Leumi/PdfUtilities/Service/2015/04/IPdfUtilitiesService/Modify"
                        style="document" />

                  <wsdl:input>
                        <soap:body use="literal" />
                  </wsdl:input>

                  <wsdl:output>
                        <soap:body use="literal" />
                  </wsdl:output>
            </wsdl:operation>

            <wsdl:operation name="Merge">
                  <soap:operation
                        soapAction="http://Leumi/PdfUtilities/Service/2015/04/IPdfUtilitiesService/Merge"
                        style="document" />

                  <wsdl:input>
                        <soap:body use="literal" />
                  </wsdl:input>

                  <wsdl:output>
                        <soap:body use="literal" />
                  </wsdl:output>
            </wsdl:operation>

            <wsdl:operation
...
```

Comment: Have you declared IPdfUtilitiesService class as abstract or declared Covert method as abstract in your webservice implementation at server side?

Comment: I didn't write server side . only client side from wsdl I got . I can ask the programmers who wrote it (in .net) . do you think it is possible it is abstract on server side ?? any way  IPdfUtilitiesService  is Interface on client side

Comment: this the client code :PdfUtilitiesService service = new PdfUtilitiesService(PdfUtilitiesService.WSDL_LOCATION, PdfUtilitiesService.SERVICE);
IPdfUtilitiesService pdfUtilities = service.getPort(IPdfUtilitiesService.class);
pdfUtilities.convert(_convert_data);

Answer (score 0):

> any way IPdfUtilitiesService is Interface on client side.

This is the isssue.

You must have been implementing this IPdfUtilitiesService interface in one of the implementaion classes, lets say class name is serviceImpl. In this class you must have overridden all operations (methods) present in wsdl.

```
 public class serviceImpl implements IPdfUtilitiesService{ 

   @Override
    Convert
   @Override
    Modify
   @Override
    Merge
   @Override
    GetFileInfo

}
```

I think you forgot to override/define Convert method here, in result your serviceImpl class becomes abstract as it is not implmenting all methods of  IPdfUtilitiesService interface. Resulting above error.

[Read this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) for abstract concept in java.

> it was noted that a class that implements an interface must implement
>   all of the interface's methods. It is possible, however, to define a
>   class that does not implement all of the interface's methods, provided
>   that the class is declared to be abstract.